# R indexing where dimnames are int?

Tags: r, matrix, indexing

I have a matrix in R where both the names of the columns and the rows are ints, i.e. M =

```
   4 5 6
7 |3 3 3
8 |4 2 1
9 |2 1 0
```

But when I try to access via the name, i.e. M[4,7] it gives an out of bounds error, because it thinks I'm trying to access the fourth row and seventh column. Any help?

Comment: You may think they are integers, but they are not. If you look at `attr(M, 'dimnames')` you will see they are stored as strings. You can do `M['7', '4']`, just like with normal string column names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, use toString() to convert the value to a string, which is what R uses to store the names as.

Comment: `as.character` would be more appropriate, as you will get errors when  trying to subset for multiple values with `toString`.  For example, check `M[, toString(c(4, 5))]` against `M[, as.character(c(4, 5))]`